# Moving an attachment from an email into an Outlook folder

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I'm trying to take attachments from mails received and move them into a folder within Outlook.

I can move the entire message, and I've also worked out how to save the attachments to a drive, but neither of these things is what I'm looking for.

I was looking at something along the lines of the below, but I'm guessing there is no `Attachment.Move` similar to `MailItem.Move`.

```vb
Sub test1()

Dim olFolder As MAPIFolder
Set olFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Mailbox - Test").Folders("Inbox")

Dim Item As Object
   
For Each Item In olFolder.Items
    Set oMail = Item
    For Each att In oMail.Attachments
        att.Move Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Enterprise Connect").Folders("Test")
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK mail folders can only hold Outlook Items (mails, notes, calendars, etc.). Actual files cannot be saved as items in folders in Outlook.

Comment: I find that when I drag and drop an attachment from an e-mail into another folder, it saves as a stand-alone file without the e-mail, so I was hoping it would be possibly to replicate this programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attachments do not exist as standalone entities in folders - what you see if a message with a single attachment. The item's message class is IPM.Document.* - when you double click on an item like that, Outlook is smart enough to open the attachment instead of showing an inspector. Take a look at such an item with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage and Item buttons).

Outlook Object Model does not allow to create `DocumentItem` objects directly. But you can create a regular `MailItem` object, add an attachment using `MailItem.Attachments.Add`, then reset the `MessageClass` property appropriately - e.g. for a ".txt" attachment, look up `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` registry key, read the default value, append it to message class (IPM.Note.txtfile).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) is an option, it exposes the [RDODocumentItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdodocumentitem.htm) and allows to create document items directly (see the examples).

Answer (score 0):

The `Attachment` class doesn't provide such methods. You need to save the attached file to the disk and then re-attach it anew to another Outlook item.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So there is no way to simply have the attachment itself in the folder, without it being attached to a mail item?

When I drag and drop the attachment manually it shows without the mail in the specified folder, so I was assuming that it would also be possible with VBA.